# How to detect if /dev/ttyGS0 is connected or not

Tags: c++, usb, ubuntu-16.04, detection

I am writing a c++ program on my linux device where I can connect the device's micro usb to my computers (host) USB port. I want my program to detect if /dev/ttyGS0 has a device connected to it or not and if it does, I want my device to connect to it right away without having to send any data from my computer. And if it disconnects, I want it to also detect that and close the port. I do not want to use libusb for this. I want to use a different library.
As of now, I am using the fcntl.h library. I'm open to any other libraries and suggestions.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm actually interested in this message being sent. How could I send and wait for a response in c++? Would this use up a lot of processing power?

Comment: I reread the question carefully and figured out that you are running Linux on a USB *device* and you want some code you can run on the USB *device* that detects whether it is connected to a USB *host* or not.  I think "GS" in ttyGS0 stands for "gadget serial".

Comment: Many serial terminals or other such programs that connect to a serial port will set the DTR and/or RTS control signals when they connect to that port.  You might be able to read those control signals in your code if the Linux gadget serial driver supports it.  Do any of the bits returned by `TIOCMGET` work for you?  (Make sure to try opening the port in a serial terminal program or something on the host side.)

Comment: I ran the code below and it returned "TIOCM_DTR  is not set". So it can't detect if the USB of my device is connected to my PC.

'int main(void)
{
    int fd, serial;

   fd = open("/dev/ttyGS0", O_RDONLY);
    ioctl(fd, TIOCMGET, &serial);
    if (serial & TIOCM_DTR)
        puts("TIOCM_DTR is not set");
    else
        puts("TIOCM_DTR is set");
    close(fd);
}
'

Comment: @DavidGrayson What did work was when I ran `udevadm monitor --kernel`
I was able to see when I plugged and unplugged the device.